# How to take attribute name list of an object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sfdatagrid

I'm a newbie Flutter programmer.
Im trying to make a generic grid widget that let me pass an object and create columns and rows dynamically.

I've made it work with an specific object but what i need is to read the names of attributes of an object to dynamically create grid column names and values so i can use the same grid for client or articles or everything.

For example i have a class for clients

```
class Client {
  int id;
  String name;
  String mail;

  Client({required this.id, required this.name, required this.mail});
}
```

then in my code retrieve a list of clients and pass that to the grid widget as List.

I just need to know how to loop the object recieved to:

1. get the list of fields names (id, name, mail)
2. then get its value for example something like

```
    var field_name = element; 
    obj.field_name.value;
```

Hope you can understand what im trying to do.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you retrieving the list can you share the data

Comment: Im making and http get that retrieves a List<Client>.
That part works well, i just need to know how to read the Client (or whatever object im retrieving) field names if its possible to get them as String or List to work with them (id, name, mail). Not the value (know how to do that), the name of them.

Comment: you have to create the future builder and in the builder return the listview

Comment: But the problem is not populating the grid or listview that is working, is how to get the name of the attributes (not the value) instead of hardcoding them as 


List<Client> list = getClients();

list.foreach((e) {print(e.id)}

i want to get that "id" word or field name to make it generic

Comment: try the code in the answer

Comment: @CodeNewbie It's not possible.  If you want dynamic variable names, use a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
FutureBuilder<List<Client>>(
            future: // your future method which return the List<Client>,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final client= snapshot.data![index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(client.name),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text(client.id),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(client.email),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            },
          },),
```

let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: Thank for your answer, this is working fine but its not the problem im facing.. 
This works great if you using Client variable for example creating Text(client.id)

i want to make something generic that let me pass Client or Article or anything and instead of doing Text(client.id) i can do something like (obj.field_name) being field_name a variable name.

Imagine you need to print the first field of the object you receive instead of client.id

Comment: i am not getting your point bro

Comment: i'll try to be more clear.. 

Imagine you have just a Text field and you recieve an object dynamic (you dont know what it is because it could be called with differents objects) and you need to print the first field of that object.

you have a function like

showFirstField(dynamic item){
     return Text( "item.field[0].name")
}

what i put between "" is what i need  to do

Comment: Hey i got your point. are you asking to have different grid widget design for specific item. say if it is article you have different widget, if it is say other than article different widget for that?

Answer (score 0):

Say you are getting List of Client Object and Class looks like this

```
class Client {
  int id;
  String name;
  String mail;

  Client({required this.id, required this.name, required this.mail});
}
```

Now if your question is how can i differentiate some Client from the list and have a separate Grid widget for them?

If yes, lets take example with above given class
We have Client with category, Design, Development etc.

We can simply have a another variable in class such as

```
class Client {
  int id;
  String name;
  String mail;
  //type variable to differentiate , could be String or enum if you know exactly 
  String type;
  Client({required this.id, required this.name, required this.mail});
}
```

and

```
GridView.builder(  
              itemCount: images.length,  
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(  
                  crossAxisCount: 2,  
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,  
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0  
              ),  
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){  

                Client item = Clients[index]; 
                if(item.type == 'Design')
                {
                    // display designClient item
                    return DesignGrid();
                }
                  if(item.type == 'Development')
                {
                    // display developmentType item
                    return DevelopmentGrid();
                }
              }
            )
```